# Pixel color inside a contour using numpy

Tags: opencv, image-processing, numpy

I am trying to constitute a numpy array containing the color hue of each pixel within a contour, using opencv 2.4. I have extracted the coordinates of all point included inside the contour using **pixelpoints = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))** (format: N x 2, where N is the number of pixels inside the contour) just as [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.ch/2012/06/contours-3-extraction.html), and I extracted the hue of all pixels within the image using **cv2.split(image)** (format: 480 , 640). So I need to obtain an array containing elements (xcoord, ycoord, hue) to 3D plot the hue colormap. Unfortunately, I am not a numpy expert, and do not find what I need in the documentation. Could someone please help? Please find below an example of what I wish to achieve.

```
import numpy as np

a=range(35,135)
hue=np.reshape(a,(10,10))
pixelpoints=np.array([[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,5],[6,6],[6,7],[7,5],[7,6],[7,7]])

print hue
print pixelpoints

result=np.array([[5,5,90],[5,6,91],[5,7,92],[6,5,100],[6,6,101],[6,7,102],[7,5,110],[7,6,111],[7,7,112]])
print result
```

Comment: Can you post some code and sample data? I think maybe you can use the mask to get the hue values by `hue = cv2.split(image)[mask]`, but I am not very sure what do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who wonder, the answer has been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16919461/2322456).

```
np.c_[pixelpoints, hue[tuple(pixelpoints.T)]]
```