# Merging two arrays under numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using Numpy, I would like to achieve the result below, given b and c. I have looked into stacking functions, but I cannot get it to work. Could someone please help?

```
import numpy as np

a=range(35,135)

b=np.reshape(a,(10,10))
c=np.array([[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,5],[6,6],[6,7],[7,5],[7,6],[7,7]])
```

The result should look like this:

```
np.array([[5,5,90],[5,6,91],[5,7,92],[6,5,100],[6,6,101],[6,7,102],
          [7,5,110],[7,6,111],[7,7,112]])
```

Comment: I'm confused -- What do `a` and `b` have to do with anything?  Also, hy were the numbers `90,91,100,101,102,110 ...` chosen?

Comment: @mgilson they correspond to `c` when viewed as two dimensional indices

Comment: @jamylak -- Ahh ... Alright ... Now I've got it :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phew!  This was a doosie.  First, we use numpy's fancy indexing to pull out the items that you want.:

```
>>> b[tuple(c.T)]
array([ 90,  91,  92, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112])
```

Then, the only thing that remains is to stack that array back against `c` using `column_stack`:

```
>>> np.column_stack((c,b[tuple(c.T)]))
array([[  5,   5,  90],
       [  5,   6,  91],
       [  5,   7,  92],
       [  6,   5, 100],
       [  6,   6, 101],
       [  6,   7, 102],
       [  7,   5, 110],
       [  7,   6, 111],
       [  7,   7, 112]])
```

Comment: The index trick c_ will do the same: `np.c_[c, b[tuple(c.T)]]`

Comment: Thank you! I think I would have died from inanition before finding the answer myself... :-)